# Activate conda environment stopped working in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I have noticed that **conda activate environment** stopped working in vscode integrated terminal with no obvious reason (I certainly did not install any new extensions, nor updated conda or vscode in the last few days).

**Expected behaviour**

After running conda activate environment I want the environment to be activated and be capable of using the environment python interpreter. Essentially it should look like this:

```
(base) lpravda-ml:~ lpravda$ conda activate rdkit-env
(rdkit-env) lpravda-ml:~ lpravda$ which python
/Users/lpravda/anaconda3/envs/rdkit-env/bin/python
```

This is what I can achieve using non-vscode terminal and work with conda as usual.

**Actual behaviour**
This happens when I type in the same set of commands in vscode integrated terminal:

```
(base) lpravda-ml:~ lpravda$ conda activate rdkit-env
(rdkit-env) lpravda-ml:~ lpravda$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

The environment seems to be switched on, however python still points to the system install python 2.7 and I have no idea why.

It used to be working like for years and now it broke down.

**Note**: When I run debugger in vscode the correct conda environment is selected and executed.

**My setup:**

```
OS: Mac OS X: 10.14.3
vscode: 1.31.1
conda: 4.6.7
```

**Update**
ongoing issue with the following update:

```
OS: Mac OS X: 10.14.3
vscode: 1.33.3
conda: 4.6.8
```

Any idea what could possibly broke down?

Comment: Might be a conda issue. Can you check that conda env has installed python? You can test with `conda install python=3.6`. Use whatever python version you think it should be.

Comment: I can confirm that. Like I said, I have been using that conda environment for over a half a year now without any problems. I'm unaware of any recent updated and it just broke. Also, when I switch on the conda environment from terminal instead of integrated vscode terminal, it works like a charm.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3834

Comment: I have the same problem with a virtaulenv installed via pip. It looks like the environment is switched on, but when running "pip list" it is clear that it points to the system install. If I activate the environment in a cmd terminal it works fine, but in the terminal in VS code it doesn't

Comment: Lukas, did you ever solve your problem? Can you outline in an answer what you did if you did anything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: trivial suggestion, but did you try doing `command+shift+P` (or equivalent) and then type python interpreter and then select the interpreter you want?

Comment: perhaps related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9636

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is still there. I'm not entirelly sure what is wrong with this. I use temporarily workaround that I run 'conda deactivate' twice and then conda activte env picks up the environment correctly. Possibly some kind of .bash profile issue.

Answer (score 2):

it is issue which you can read about it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3834), but I find this [solution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments)
which solve the issue in this version. Also, as community said the problem with python interpreter and env gonna fix in next major update.

Comment: can you be more precise what exactly you did?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an workspace folder
2. Inside the create file post the following code:

```
{
  "folders": [
      {
          "path": "."
      }
  ],
  "settings": {
      "python.condaPath": "/home/pcuser/anaconda3/condabin/conda",
      "python.pythonPath": "/home/pcuser/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python",
      "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
      "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,      
  }
}
```

3. Save configuration and close vscode
4. Open vscode.

It will select automatically the conda enviroment (Should appear at the bottom left of vscode). Inside terminal 'my_env' will also be selected. If vscode doesn't select the 'Python Selected Interpreter' before you open the terminal the my_env inside terminal won't be selected. Open the terminal after the my_env is selected by vscode